# I.Q. Puzzle with grey and black dots that I cannot solve

Tags: pattern

[image]

So, I have been stuck on this for quite some time, but I haven’t found a solution yet! The things that I’ve noticed so far:

- The black dots are 6-7-8-10, while the grey dots are always two
- One grey dot is always in the same position, but the other seems to be moving horizontally.

I thought about a ‘game of life’ scenario, where the black circles are on/off based on the neighbors in the previous round, but it still doesn’t make sense (I think!).

Any chance you can figure this out?

Comment: My initial reaction is that is either 2 or 3. 2-6 have three similar black dots across the bottom and the grey dot in the same place as the puzzle. 1 is the odd one out. 2-4 additionally have the second grey dot in the same position each time (which follows with the movement around the grid). 2 and 3 are opposites when it comes to the first two columns of black dots. Not sure after that however

Comment: re: close votes - this puzzle is not claimed to be the own work of the op. It still should have attribution, but I don't think it deserves deletion, as the author does not claim as own - assume good faith

Comment: Welcome to PSE Neoandrew! When you post a puzzle that is not your own, you need to share where you got that puzzle from. I've given you leniency this time, but make sure you put a link to the source or say where the puzzle is from if possible.

Comment: @micsthepick it wont be deleted, just closed till attribution is added